# Calculate packet size from traffic dump

Tags: pandas, networking, network-programming, wireshark, pcap

I have a traffic dump in csv file containing packet arrival time, frame length and boolean values for multiple flags.

Can someone please explain how to calculate packet size from the traffic dump.

I further want to generate distribution of the packet size in python.

Comment: hi @streamer will be great if you take a moment to look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples
It will help you to get your question answered faster

Comment: A packet is the payload of the frame, so you must determine if the frame length you have includes the FCS or only the frame header, then subtract the size of the frame header (and FCS, if included) from the frame length to arrive at the packet size. For standard ethernet, the frame header size is 18 octets (FCS is four octets).